# Adding Empty Columns in a data frame based on variable names of previous columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

| ID | director_name | vp_name | lead_name | funding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | C | E | 100$ |
| 2 | B | D | G | 200$ |

I want to add empty columns for genders based on variables that have `_name` in their headers to look like the following

| ID | director_name | director_g | vp_name | vp_g | lead_name | lead_g | funding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A |  | C |  | E |  | 100$ |
| 2 | B |  | D |  | G |  | 200$ |

All the internet help has been based on conditions that are based on values in a variable, but none on headers. At the same time, I am not sure how to give them specific names. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Greetings! It would be helpful to provide a minimal reproducible dataset for us to work with. One way is by using `dput`. You can see how to use this command in the following video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1):

Here are methods with base R and `dplyr`:

```
## base
names_to_add = grep("_", names(df), value = T)
names_to_add = sub(pattern = "_.*", replacement = "_g", x = names_to_add)
df[names_to_add] = ""
df
#   ID director_name vp_name lead_name funding director_g vp_g lead_g
# 1  1             A       C         E    100$                       
# 2  2             B       D         G    200$  

## dplyr version
# make sure to re-initialize `df` before running this version

library(dplyr)
df = df %>%
  mutate(across(contains("_"), \(x) "", .names = "{.col}_g")) %>%
  rename_with(.fn = sub, pattern = "_.*", replacement = "_g", .cols = contains("_g"))
df
#   ID director_name vp_name lead_name funding director_g vp_g lead_g
# 1  1             A       C         E    100$                       
# 2  2             B       D         G    200$
```

As asked, this initializes the new columns to `""` values. I'd usually prefer missing values `NA`, which you might want to consider.

---

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'ID  director_name   vp_name     lead_name   funding
1   A   C   E   100$
2   B   D   G   200$', header = T)
```

Comment: Or a one-liner `mutate(across(contains("_"), \(x) "", .names = "{sub('_.*', '_g', .col)}"))`

Comment: Ooh, I didn't realize you could do functions inside glue brackets. Thanks!